# CorrelationTest vs PearsonCorrelationTest

Tags: probability-or-statistics, correlation

I understand that these two functions consider different null hypotheses. However, although I can reproduce the calculation related to PearsonCorrelationTest from scratch, I cannot reproduce the p-value obtained by the CorrelationTest function. When I use the Fisher transform and the null hypothesis rho=0 (following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) I obtained values close to those obtained by PearsonCorrelationTest and not by CorrelationTest.
My goal is to implement CorrelationTest in Python. Python (scipy) offers a function that calculates the p-value with the same null hypothesis of PearsonCorrelationTest but I need to calculate according to the Mathematica function CorrelationTest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:**  Added at the end what happens when the tests for normality have small P-values.

The difference in the results of the two functions is not due to considering different null hypotheses.  They simply use two different methods to obtain P-values.  (But why they don't use the same method or at least both give the two options is probably that the development histories of the two functions were not done by the same folks.)

Here is a demonstration as to what both functions actually do.

```
(* Generate some data *)
SeedRandom[12345];
n = 100;
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, 0.5], n];

PearsonCorrelationTest[data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]], "TestDataTable"]
```

[image: PearsonCorrelationTest results]

```
CorrelationTest[data, 0, {"TestDataTable", "PearsonCorrelation"}]
```

[image: CorrelationTest results]

What `PearsonCorrelationTest` does...

```
r = Correlation[data][[1, 2]];
z2 = r Sqrt[(n - 2)/(1 - r^2)]
(* 6.4355 *)
pValue2 = 2 Min[1 - CDF[StudentTDistribution[n - 2], z2], 
  CDF[StudentTDistribution[n - 2], z2]]
(* 4.54849*10^-9 *)
```

What `CorrelationTest` does...

```
fisherZTransform[r_, ρ0_, n_] := (ArcTanh[r] - ArcTanh[ρ0] - ρ0/(2 (n - 1))) Sqrt[n - 3]
r = Correlation[data][[1, 2]];
z1 = fisherZTransform[r, 0, n]
(* 6.02055 *)
pValue1 = Probability[Abs[x] > Abs[z1], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]
(* 1.73824*10^-9 *)
```

**When the data doesn't pass a normality test**

When a test of normality (and which test is not specifically indicated in the documentation) is not satistfied, `PearsonCorrelationTest` provides a warning but the same output as if the normality test was satisfied.  `CorrelationTest` then produces only the results for Spearman's $\rho$.

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[LogMultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}], n];

PearsonCorrelationTest[data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]], TestDataTable"]
```

[image: Warning message about lack of normality]

[image: Results from PearsonCorrelationTest with non-normal data]

```
r = Correlation[data][[1, 2]]
(* -0.0532481 *)
z2 = r Sqrt[(n - 2)/(1 - r^2)];
pValue2 = 2 Min[1 - CDF[StudentTDistribution[n - 2], z2], 
  CDF[StudentTDistribution[n - 2], z2]]
(* 0.598777 *)

CorrelationTest[data, 0, "TestDataTable"]
```

[image: Results from CorrelationTest with non-normal data]

Comment: I still have some doubts when the data is not normally distributed, If we try with:

data=RandomVariate[LogMultinormalDistribution[{0,0},{{1,0},{0,1}}],n];

PearsonCorrelationTest gives 0.828541 after nothing that normality fails.
However, CorrelationTest[] gives 0.410975 and there is no message for normality failure.

Performing both tests from scratch that you suggest, I am only can reproduce the result of  PearsonCorrelationTest. However, these tests fail for normality.

I wish to understand how Mathematica computes CorrelationTest[] when the test for normality fails. Thanks!

Comment: You should have doubts in trusting whether any function handles non-bivariate normal data in an appropriate manner.  `PearsonCorrelationTest` just gives a warning while `CorrelationTest` switches from the Pearson correlation to Spearman correlation when the test used does not indicate bivariate normality.  I'll update the answer a bit later.